# Sending push notifications in non-native app (web-app)?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application, mobile-webkit, web-push

This is my first post on the forum, so please educate me if I got the tag, forum or content wrong.

I am developing an app targeting iPhone and Android, which is a real-time, location based social network. The app will not be deployed through market place/app-store.

From what I understand my only option is to make a web-app (HTML5/JS). All the functionality should be support except for a need to send push notifications to other users.

The options, I have considered are:
- Send an email, however this is not very real time.
- Send an SMS, however this has some significant costs associated.
- Linking to an IM of choice for the user and sending the notification through that IM

As I understanding it all cross-platform frameworks sich as PhoneGab compiles to native and requires to be deployed through the app stores to take advantage of their APIs (correct me if I am wrong).

Any easy work-around for a location based, push notification app framework to be offered outside the app stores?

EDIT: I expect to distribute the app via a web-site.

EDIT: The app service is a dating concept on the slightly sleezy side so I am afraid it will not pass the review gates and thus not be possible to distribute in the stores. Of course I could try using PhoneGap or Titanium and then do the webapp if it doesn't pass.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: You've said how you **don't** want to distribute the app, but how **do** you want to distribute the app?

Comment: @MarcusAdams I expect to distribute the app through a website

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to build a webapp ("progressive web app" as they're calling them these days) that can send push notifications even after the page has been closed.

These work today in Chrome for Android (and other browsers seem to be implementing support), but there is no support on iOS.

Check out [this demo](https://simple-push-demo.appspot.com/), and this guide explains how to do it: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

**If you distribute (native) iOS apps outside of the App Store (yes, this is possible in various ways), then you cannot use Apple's push notification service.**

You can still release native iOS apps, outside of the app store.

One way, if your app is open source, you can distribute your app via [MacBuildServer](http://macbuildserver.com/github/opensource/). Another way is via an Enterprise distribution.

Most authentic Android devices support [side loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideloading) of apps, so they could download your native app from your website.

If you want to write a web app (that runs inside their web browser), then you cannot use Apple push notifications and probably no alternative "notification" service will suffice.

Most "cross platform" push notification services still tie into the native APNS service for iOS. There's just no replacement for apple push notifications.

Alternatives include polling a server (which only works while your app is in the foreground) or simply leaving a TCP connection open, waiting.

Comment: Good insight and seems like there is no way around trying to get through the native review gate...

Answer (score 0):

Question: do you want the push to occur only when the user has an open browser with the web application open?

I'm asking the question since you insist on the fact that you must do a web app and not native apps.

If it's the case, you may use some javascript push libraries. But be aware the even if it's js, you'll have an additional socket connection open (in addition to the native one for the push). So this will be battery consuming, which could be a reason why people would stop using your app.

If you want real time notification, you'd better address the native push mechanism on each platform (maybe with phonegap or titanium)

Comment: Yes, the challenge is that I want to find a way to do push notifications when the app is not active. That's why I figure I have to link to some native notification outside the app. Email is possible but not very real time. SMS is more real time but costly. IM could be a way. I am assuming other have had the same challenge and may have found a way to "solve" it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like https://pushover.net/ ?

As I understand it it's a separate app that allows users to get notifications from you. Since it is a separate app it would get you around the review gates, but it might require slightly more effort from your users.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you can build a hybrid app which will allow you to access both native as well as web functionality. To achieve this you can consider using Phonegap. This will allow you to use Push Notification service too.

You can consider Test Flight which is a 3rd party software for your app distribution on Android and iOS platform. Test Flight is free and recently acquired by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a native app (or you use a native wrapper like Phonegap around an html/javascript app) you have to distribute it through the App store.

If you go for a website you can send push notifications using the **Push API** (there are service like [Pushpad](https://pushpad.xyz) - I am the founder - that make it easier). Currently the Push API is supported by all major browsers, except Safari on iOS.